# show online user in chatroom sidebar

Tags: php, jquery, chat

i program chatroom but cant find way for show online and offline users.
i used session for online user . when user login page and not empty session update database and online 1 .
now how know user logout from chat or close browser . i know whith session time or catch can do this but i cant write suitablecode. anyone can help me and put complete code here?
thanks for answer

for show online:

```
session_start();
include("config.php");
connect();
$sql="SELECT `username` FROM `user` WHERE `online`=1";
$result=mysql_query($sql) or die (mysql_error());
if(mysql_num_rows($result)>0)
{
for ($i=0;$i<mysql_num_rows($result);$i++)
{
echo ('<b style="color:green;margin-left:10px;margin-top:10px;">'.mysql_result($result,$i,0).'</b><br>');
if($_SESSION['user']!=""
}
```

Comment: Which technique are you using for realtime-communication? Websockets or ajax longpolling or something different?

Comment: i used ajax for find online user and chat

Answer (score 1):

You can use the php script runs on a schedule that will be update status to offline when user not on site some time.

To do this, you should sometimes send the user state to the server, by ajax, for example, and store it in database.

updated..

js, jquery function for send status to php every 500ms.

```
function upd_status() {
    $.get('/php.php', function(data) {
        setTimeout(upd_status,500);
    });
}
upd_status();
```

on php side.

```
// I do not know where is user id, but it should be in session
$uid = $_SESSION['user']['uid'];
settype($uid, 'int');

$sql = "UPDATE user SET status = 1, timestamp = ". time() ." WHERE id = ". $uid .";
```

on cron script

```
$sql = "UPDATE user SET status = 0 WHERE timestamp < ". (time()-60*5);
```

Comment: it will work even through mysql_query() without additional checks, but I recommend using PDO

Comment: on cron script??? and 500ms for chatroom whith 1000 online user can be presure server?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron
You can use any scheduler.
>500ms
This value may be larger, it's set in depending on the load. Also it's not just 500ms, is 500ms + request time.

Comment: PDO not suitable because no suported loop sql select

Answer (score 0):

You can put simple "if" operation to check if there's session time is shortest than realtime.

example.

In database make column last_activity in users.When user sends message make a query to update that column, last activity with time();

And just check if there's last_activity from database shortest than timeout, in this case you can set $timeout variable for timeout.
Here's code:

```
<?php # make while loop from users where online = 1
$last_activity_from_database = $row['last_activity']; 
$timeout                     = time()-600; # 10 minutes
if($last_activity_from_database < $timeout){
    mysql_query("UPDATE users SET online='0'");
}
?>
```

You should make AJAX call.

Comment: When a user sends a message or create js function that check's every minute, last activity..

Comment: maybe user only see the chatroom and dont send message . how i create js function for this case?